# What does double.MaxValue and double.MinValue mean in the following context?

Tags: c#

What does `double.MaxValue` and `double.MinValue` mean in the following context:

```
double minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
minX = double.MaxValue;
minY = double.MaxValue;
maxX = double.MinValue;
maxY = double.MinValue;

for(int i = 0 ; i < HPts.BranchCount; i++){
  foreach(Point3d pt in HPts.Branch(i)){
    if(minX > pt.X){
      minX = pt.X;
    }

    if(minY > pt.Y){
      minY = pt.Y;
    }

    if(maxX < pt.X){
      maxX = pt.X;
    }

    if(maxY < pt.Y){
      maxY = pt.Y;
    }
```

Comment: They are properties of the `double` type.

Answer (score 6):

They are the maximum and minimum values you can store in a `double`.

This is used to determine the min/max X and Y locations.  For example, by starting with `minX` set to the maximum allowable value for a double, the first time through the loop, `minX > pt.X` will be true, which will cause `minX` to set to the first X value.  Eventually, the minimum value for X will be stored there.

Answer (score 2):

When you are looking for a minimum value in the collection, one common approach is to initialize your result to a value that exceeds any possible number in your collection. This way the very first comparison is going to be successful, making the initial value the new minimum. double.MaxValue supplies such a value: other valid doubles are less than it.

You do this when it is allowed for your collection to be empty; otherwise, you could initialize both the current min and max to the initial element of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Max and Min value that is supported for a double-precision floating-point number.  The are used a default/initial values.

Positive/Negative -->  1.7976931348623157E+308.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx